# Send Email with codeigniter(configuration) from my own server

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, smtp

In the past I have already send Email through the google smtp now I want to send Email from my own server.

I have followed [this example](http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/150003/#1055124) to setup my email config file. This is how my email.php file looks like:

```
$config['useragent']        = 'CodeIgniter';        
$config['protocol']         = 'mail';        
$config['mailpath']         = '/usr/sbin/sendmail';
$config['smtp_host']        = 'localhost';
$config['smtp_user']        = 'noreply@publish.mmedija.com';
$config['smtp_pass']        = 'testtest';
$config['smtp_port']        = 25;
$config['smtp_timeout']     = 5;
$config['wordwrap']         = TRUE;
$config['wrapchars']        = 76;
$config['mailtype']         = 'text';
$config['charset']          = 'utf-8';
$config['validate']         = FALSE;
$config['priority']         = 3;
$config['crlf']             = "\r\n";
$config['newline']          = "\r\n";
$config['bcc_batch_mode']   = FALSE;
$config['bcc_batch_size']   = 200;
```

I have an Apache server. I have DirectAdmin software, with which I have setup an email account(noreply@publish.mmedija.com) with password(testtest). Are this the stmp_user and smtp_pass that I have to set in the config file.

It is strange, because:

```
$this->email->send()
```

returns True, but no Email is sent. print_debugger returns this:

```
Your message has been successfully sent using the following protocol: mail
User-Agent: CodeIgniter
Date: Thu, 11 Jul 2013 08:36:13 +0200
From: "Publishwall.si" 
Return-Path: 
Reply-To: "noreply@publish.mmedija.com" 
X-Sender: noreply@publish.mmedija.com
X-Mailer: CodeIgniter
X-Priority: 3 (Normal)
Message-ID: <51de525d9d15a@publish.mmedija.com>
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
=?utf-8?Q?Publishwall.si_-_Aktivacija_ra=c4=8duna?=
test
```

But I have not received the email. Also the field "Reply-To" in the debugger is not the one that I set to send the mail to. Maybe there is something wrong with my configuration in php.ini:

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/smtp
SMTP = localhost
; http://php.net/smtp-port
smtp_port = 25

; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/sendmail-from
;sendmail_from = me@example.com

; For Unix only.  You may supply arguments as well (default: "sendmail -t -i").
; http://php.net/sendmail-path
;sendmail_path =
```

Comment: This happens when you try sending email from local server.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check your mail server logs.  These should tell you whether or not the mail server is even receiving the message for queuing from your script - and if so, what is happening when it tries to deliver the message to the remote MTA.

Comment: For 1and1, I realized the SMTP port for shared hosting is not 25 but 465. This may help you if you're on 1and1. If not, make sure you have all details about your server correct.

Answer (score 0):

Where are you sending it to? Try sending to your other email. I know I had an issue sending to same domain when I was using google apps.

Try sending it to hotmail or yahoo.